# Replace multiple value in one field and value from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, optimization, replace

Hello i have two table

table player

```
id     Player           Position 
1      Messi            1,2,4 
2      C.Ronaldo        1,2,3 
3      Neymar           2,3
```

table position

```
id             pos 
1              CF 
2              ST 
3              WF 
4              MF
```

and i want output like this

```
id     player         pos 
1      Messi          CF,ST,MF 
2      C.Ronaldo      CF,ST,WF 
3      Neymar         ST,WF
```

my sql fidle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf206/1

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? Please only use the applicable one.

Comment: **Do not store comma separated values please normalize your structure first**

Comment: In italy we have a saying that can be roughly translated to "Not even a king can have whatever he wants". Basically, you won't get code for free if you don't show first what have you tried. I won't waste my time for somebody that doesn't even want to invest some time for himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't use a comma separated field like this. Hard to read, inefficient and will cause major problems in the future.

However it is possible to do what you want like this, if the order of the positions for a player are not important:-

```
SELECT a.id, a.Player, GROUP_CONCAT(b.pos)
FROM player a
INNER JOIN position b
ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.position) > 0
GROUP BY a.id, a.player
```

To keep the order you could try this (not tested):-

```
SELECT a.id, a.Player, GROUP_CONCAT(b.pos ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.position))
FROM player a
INNER JOIN position b
ON FIND_IN_SET(b.id, a.position) > 0
GROUP BY a.id, a.player
```

Comment: this result from your sql only one row. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf206/6

Comment: Fixed bug now (forgot the group by clause.....)

Comment: it's work thanks before. :D